# Converting a Nested List into a Pandas DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list that looks like this:

```
['2016-01-05', '2017-02-03', '2018-01-25', ['File_2016.csv', 'File_2017.csv', 'File_2018.csv']]
```

Which is an output of a user entered field, and the partition of the data, where the first set of items ('2016-01-05', '2017-02-03', '2018-01-25') are the user entered fields, and the second set ('File_2016.csv', 'File_2017.csv', 'File_2018.csv') are the corresponding files.

What I'd like to do is create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date             File
2016-01-05      File_2016.csv
2017-02-03      File_2017.csv
2018-01-25      File_2018.csv
```

My code looks like this:

```
my_list = [input('enter the start date for file %s: ' % i) for i in list(filenames)]
```

Where filenames is a list of the Files above, and I append filenames to the list after the above user inputs.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is better than what you've got now, but here's another way of doing it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l[:-1], l[-1])), columns=['Date', 'File'])
df
         Date           File
0  2016-01-05  File_2016.csv
1  2017-02-03  File_2017.csv
2  2018-01-25  File_2018.csv
```

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you!!